# Is an Object/Reference/Pointer Recreated to Add const

Tags: c++, parameters, constants, parameter-passing

Given the code:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T){}
```

What is actually happening behind the scenes when i do the following:

```
int main(){
    string a;
    string* pA = &a;

    foo(string("test"));
    foo(ref(A));
    foo(pA);

    return 0;
}
```

Does `foo` get a copy of these objects that is `const`? Or is `foo` now referencing this object but cannot change the contents?

Comment: Did you mean to write `foo(*pA)` on the last call?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No, I wanted to know what happens when a pointer gets converted to a `const` pointer.

Comment: @JonathanMee: It doesn't get converted, just copied. In the function, it's a constant pointer `string * const`, not a pointer-to-constant `const string*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your function takes a parameter by value, it gets a copy. Const-ness does not play into it.

```
foo(string("test"))
```

In this case, a temporary object is created. If your compiler applies [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), the value for the parameter would be created "in place". In other words, there would be only a constructor call `std::string("test")`, not a constructor call followed by a copy constructor call followed by a destructor call for the temporary.

```
foo(rA);
```

In this case a new `std::string` would be created using a copy constructor, copying the content of `a` to which `rA` is a reference.

```
foo(ref(A));
```

In this case a temporary instance of `std::reference_wrapper<std::string>` is created. Again, return value optimization will make sure that it is created in place, and not copied.

```
foo(pA);
```

In this case the pointer would be copied in the same way that pointers are copied when they are passed by value. The value of the pointer is not going to change ([demo](http://ideone.com/PG9TVV)).

Answer (score 1):

> Does `foo` get a copy of these objects that is `const`?

Yes. In the first two cases, it's a copy of the string `a`; in the third, it's a copy of the pointer `pA`.

> Or is `foo` now referencing this object but cannot change the contents?

No. If you wanted it to take a reference, you'd declare it

```
template <typename T>    // note: lower-case "typename"
void foo(const T&){}
                ^
```

or specify a reference type for the template argument instead of leaving the compiler to deduce a non-reference

```
foo<string&>(a);     // or <const string&> for const enforcement
```

or, as you mention in the comments, pass a reference wrapper

```
foo(std::ref(a));    // or std::cref for const enforcement
```

Comment: Hmm maybe I should change my code just a touch. What if the second `foo` call was, `foo(ref(a));`?

Comment: @JonathanMee: As in `std::ref`? That would pass a reference wrapper to the function, with a similar effect to passing the `string` by reference.

Comment: @MikeSeymore And what happens to the reference? Is it copied, moved, or recreated with `const`?

Comment: @JonathanMee: The reference wrapper contains a reference as a member. It's copied along with the wrapper. Within the function, the wrapper is `const`, but the reference isn't. Use `cref` rather than `ref` if you want a constant reference.